# REACT Delete Element in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble deleting an element inside an array of objects. I want to simply delete an object inside the array. When I try to use .IndexOf(). It gives me back -1. is there a way to do this without creating a reference to each object.

This is my Array of objects.

```
   let todos = [{
      id: 1,
      task: 'Finish This React App'
    },{
      id: 2,
      task: 'Do Another App'
    },{
      id: 3,
      task: 'Pass data from the parent to the child and reverse'
    }]

let task = {id:2,task:'Do Another App'}

let todosArray = this.props.todos

todosArray.indexOf(task,0) //= -1
```

Overall I want to only have objects 1 and 3 inside the todos array.

Comment: This isn't a react question.

Comment: @brian-bier didn't specify this, but in react you should never modify the original value when changing state. I believe his question is about achieving this. Not just about removing from an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method always returns `-1` since the objects reference is not the same.

You can use **[`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)**, **[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**, **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** methods.

```js
let todos = [{
  id: 1,
  task: 'Finish This React App'
}, {
  id: 2,
  task: 'Do Another App'
}, {
  id: 3,
  task: 'Pass data from the parent to the child and reverse'
}]

let task = {
  id: 2,
  task: 'Do Another App'
};
let keys = Object.keys(task);

// remove element from the array by index
todos.splice(
  // get the index of the element
  todos.findIndex(function(obj) {
    // check all property values are equal
    return keys.every(function(k) {
      return task[k] === obj[k];
    });
    // if you want to check only the `id` property then     // you can avoid the above codes and use
    // return obj.id === task.id;
  }), 1);

console.log(todos)
```

**Note :** Above methods only works if there is no nested object and array property value.

Comment: todos.splice changes the original array, which is not something you would want for managing state in a typical react application. If that's the case you will want to use todos.filter(...) to create a new array with the modified contents. Alternatively copy the array (todos = [...todos]) and delete elements from the copy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use filter in pure vanillia ES6 :

```
var array = todos.filter(item => item.id === 1 || item.id === 3);
```

Comment: This should be the validated answer but you can do it the other way and do `todos.filter(item => item.id !== 2);`